# Merging in PySpark (both left and right)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, merge

What is the equivalent code in PySpark to merge two different dataframe (both left and right)?

```
df_merge = pd.merge(t_df, d_df, left_on='a_id', right_on='d_id', how='inner')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark: How to merge dataframes like Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096435/pyspark-how-to-merge-dataframes-like-pandas)

Comment: Yes, that's a useful link. However, these terms `left_on='a_id', right_on='d_id'` made me confused to use `join` in a correct form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html) is the equivalent of `merge` in pandas.

The equivalent PySpark logic for the merge code you had shared would be

```py
t_df.join(d_df, t_df["a_id"] == d_df["d_id"], "inner")
```